# WP check_ajax_referer() is not working

Tags: php

I am developing a reservation form using ajax. I am facing 2 problems. One is When I use the shortcode of the form in the page or post, showing the form in the WP backend 5.2.3 version. Another one is when I check the nonce field using this function check_ajax_referer(). The form does not appear in the view page. Only showing -1 in the view page.

```
/*
Plugin Name: Ajax Reservation Form
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: Reservation Form
Version: 1.0
Author: Ataur Rahman
Author URI: md-ataur.github.io
License: GPL v2 or later
License URI:  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain:  ajax-reservation-form
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );
if(!class_exists('AjaxReservationForm')){
    class AjaxReservationForm{
        public function __construct(){
            add_action('plugins_loaded', array($this, 'ajaxrf_load_textdomain' ));
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'ajaxrf_enqueue_scripts'));
            add_shortcode( 'ajax_reservation_form', array($this,'ajaxrf_shortcode' ));
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxRSF', array($this, 'AjaxdataProcess') );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxRSF', array($this, 'AjaxdataProcess') );
        }
        public function ajaxrf_load_textdomain(){
            load_plugin_textdomain( 'ajax-reservation-form', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
        }
        public function ajaxrf_enqueue_scripts(){
            wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'assets/public/css/bootstrap.min.css');
            wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-reservation-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'assets/public/js/ajax-reservation.js', array( 'jquery' ), time(), true );
            $ajaxUrl = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php');
            wp_localize_script( 'ajax-reservation-js', 'url', array('ajaxUrl' => $ajaxUrl) );
        }

        public static function AjaxdataProcess(){
            if (check_ajax_referer( 'rsf_nonce_action', 'snonce' )) {
                $RFname     = sanitize_text_field( isset($_POST['RFname'])?$_POST['RFname']:'' );
                $RFemail    = sanitize_text_field( isset($_POST['RFemail'])?$_POST['RFemail']:'' );
                $RFphone    = sanitize_text_field( isset($_POST['RFphone'])?$_POST['RFphone']:'' );
                $RFperson   = sanitize_text_field( isset($_POST['RFperson'])?$_POST['RFperson']:'' );
                $RFdate     = sanitize_text_field( isset($_POST['RFdate'])?$_POST['RFdate']:'' );
                $RFtime     = sanitize_text_field( isset($_POST['RFtime'])?$_POST['RFtime']:'' );
                $RFMessage  = sanitize_text_field( isset($_POST['RFMessage'])?$_POST['RFMessage']:'' );                 
                $data = array(
                    'RFname' => $RFname,
                    'RFemail' => $RFemail,
                    'RFphone' => $RFphone,
                    'RFperson' => $RFperson,
                    'RFdate' => $RFdate,
                    'RFtime' => $RFtime,
                    'RFMessage' => $RFMessage,
                );      
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($data);
                echo "</pre>";  
            }
        }

        public static function ajax_reservation_form(){         
            ?>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="arform">
                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'rsf_nonce_action', 'rsf_nonce_field');?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="label">Name</label>                
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RFname">                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="RFemail">                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone" class="label">Phone</label>                            
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RFphone">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="persons" class="label">Number of Persons</label>
                            <select name="persons" id="RFperson" class="form-control">
                                <option value="1">1 person</option>
                                <option value="2">2 person</option>
                                <option value="3">3 person</option>
                                <option value="4">4 person</option>
                                <option value="5">5 person</option>
                            </select>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="date" class="label">Date</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="RFdate">                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="time" class="label">Time</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="RFtime" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="RFMessage" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>                 
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <button id="reserveForm" class="btn btn-primary">Reserve Now</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        public function ajaxrf_shortcode(){
            self::AjaxdataProcess();
            self::ajax_reservation_form();
        }
    }
    new AjaxReservationForm;
}
```

> Javascript

```
;(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#reserveForm').on('click', function(){
            $.post(url.ajaxUrl, {
                action: 'ajaxRSF',
                snonce: $('#rsf_nonce_field').val(),
                RFname: $('#RFname').val(),
                RFemail: $('#RFemail').val(),
                RFphone: $('#RFphone').val(),
                RFperson: $('#RFperson').val(),
                RFdate: $('#RFdate').val(),
                RFtime: $('#RFtime').val(),
                RFMessage: $('#RFMessage').val()
            }, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });         
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please help me
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352177/data-fetch-and-delete-by-ajax-request/352180#352180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One is When I use the shortcode of the form in the page or post,
>   showing the form in the WP backend 5.2.3 version.

That happens because your shortcode is echoing the output. A shortcode should always return the output, but if you need to echo it, then you should use output buffering:

```php
public function ajaxrf_shortcode(){
    // Turn on output buffering.
    ob_start();

    self::AjaxdataProcess();
    self::ajax_reservation_form(); // echo the form

    // Turn off output buffering and then return the output echoed via the above functions.
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

> Another one is when I check the nonce field using this function
>   `check_ajax_referer()`. The form does not appear in the view page.
>   Only showing -1 in the view page.

First off, why are you calling `AjaxdataProcess()` in the shortcode function (`ajaxrf_shortcode()`)? Is it because you are allowing non-AJAX form submissions?

But that "-1" could happen if the (AJAX) request verification failed (e.g. due a missing or an expired nonce) and by default, [`check_ajax_referer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_ajax_referer/) will call either [`wp_die()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/) if doing an AJAX request or `die()` otherwise.

And to prevent WordPress/PHP execution from being halted upon failure of the request verification, set the third parameter to `false` when you call `check_ajax_referer()`:

```php
check_ajax_referer( 'rsf_nonce_action', 'snonce', false )
```

#### If you want to allow non-AJAX form submissions...

1. Make sure the relevant form fields are assigned the proper `name`; e.g.:

   ```html
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RFname" name="RFname">
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="RFemail" name="RFemail">
   ```
2. You should also set the form's `method` to `post` (because `AjaxdataProcess()` is using `$_POST`):

   ```html
   <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="arform" method="post">
   ```
3. Although your form *does* include the proper nonce, WordPress/PHP doesn't recognize it because you're not using the proper name — you used `snonce` with `check_ajax_referer()` (and in your JS script), but in the form, the name is `rsf_nonce_field`:

   - In `ajax_reservation_form()` — **the value of the *second* parameter for [`wp_nonce_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/) should match the value of the second parameter for `check_ajax_referer()`** (and in fact, same goes to the first parameter..):

     ```php
     <?php wp_nonce_field( 'rsf_nonce_action', 'rsf_nonce_field');?>
     ```

   So that `rsf_nonce_field` should be changed to `snonce`.